# Android slide out view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering how to achieve some kind of draggable view. I am **not** speaking about the navigation drawer!
Several other applications implement this kind of views, for example the new stock Android Lollipop Calculator application. There you can drag out the extended symbols view from the right hand corner.
Another application is Google maps. When checking out a location, it's possible to extend the location information by dragging up the bottom information view. 
It appears that there are two points where the view is able to lock in, meaning that when pulling the view up to a specific point and releasing, will result in the drawer not closing entirely but to align to the specific locking points.

How is that achieved or is a library required?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The stock calculator app appears to use ViewPager to achieve the slideout numberpad. It's a part of android, no libraries so that would be a good starting point.

[Here's the class in question](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.0_r1/com/android/calculator2/CalculatorPadViewPager.java?av=f) (Rest of the code to the left)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check this out